# How to sort json data by date and time

Tags: jq

I'd like to take some covid 19 JSON data and sort the results by date and time but the date and time are 2 separate keys. How would I go about using jq tool to do this? The JSON data is at https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset/nsw-covid-19-case-locations/resource/f3a28eed-8c2a-437b-8ac1-2dab3cf760f9 and it looks like this:

```json
{
  "date": "2020-12-24",
  "title": "Venues",
  "data": {
    "monitor": [
      {
        "Venue": "Hungry Ghost Café",
        "Address": "20 Avalon Parade, Avalon, NSW 2107",
        "Date": "Sunday 13 December 2020",
        "Time": "9:30am to 11am",
        ...
      },
      {
        "Venue": "Hungry Ghost Café",
        "Address": "20 Avalon Parade, Avalon, NSW 2107",
        "Date": "Tuesday 15 December 2020",
        "Time": "9:30am to 11am",
        "Alert": "Monitor for symptoms",
        ...
      },
      {
        "Venue": "Woolworths",
        "Address": "74 Old Barrenjoey Road, Avalon Beach, NSW 2107",
        "Date": "Saturday 12 December 2020",
        "Time": "12pm to 12:15pm",
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: ug,the date and time aren't in a usable format.

Comment: A strategy to get it done is to convert `Date`, `Time` into epoch's seconds and then sort entries by then. However, your source data sometime contain non-convertible time formats, like  `"Time": "Strength and Conditioning Class"`, or `"Time": ""`, etc. How would you like to go about those records?

Comment: @p4guru - I believe you would most probably receive fewer downvotes if (a) you clarified what the ordering should be in the case that the Time is a range; (b) you followed the [mcve] guidelines more closely; and (c) you showed one of your attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sort_by/1` on the fields, you'll have to either normalize the date/time formats or conditionally parse them out using `strptime/1`. It returns an array of the date fields in significant order combine to a single array and sort_by will do the rest.

```
.data.monitor
  | sort_by([
    (.Date | strptime("%A %d %B %Y")),
    (.Time | split(" ")[0] | if contains(":") then
      strptime("%I:%M%p")
    else
      strptime("%I%p")
    end)
  ])
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/iRse0LTSYF)

Comment: or convert to a full date and time string and parse once, but a little more work needed.

Comment: [It's not really any more work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65445765/589924)

Comment: @ikegami `data.monitor[26].Date` contains a [non-breaking space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) and [`strptime("%A %d %B %Y")` fails](https://jqplay.org/s/barjs165Lw). Besides none of these answers sort `data.isolated` and `data.negative`.

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks for that example. The source link data json format seems to have changed and your example seems to work perfectly to order by ascending date/time. They seem to have remoted data.isolated and data.negative from source json format now

Answer (score 2):

```
def mysort:
   map(
      .epoch =
         try (
            [
               ( .Date | split(" ")[0:4] | .[] ),
               ( .Time | split(" ")[0] | if . == "All" then "12am" else . end )
            ] | join(" ") |
            strptime(
               if contains(":") then
                  "%A %d %B %Y %I:%M%p"
               else
                  "%A %d %B %Y %I%p"
               end
            ) |
            mktime
         )
         catch -1
   ) |
   sort_by(.epoch) |
   map( del(.epoch) );

.data[] |= mysort
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/xbw5qGD1vW)

This is a variation of @Jeff Mercado's work. There are five differences:

- It returns the entire data set instead of just part of it.
- It sorts not just `.data.monitor`, but `.data.negative` and `.data.isolate` as well (if present).
- It handles dates of `$date1 to $date2 inclusive`.
- It handles times of `All day`.
- It uses a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to reduce the number of times a sorting key is generated.
- Bad inputs are tolerated. (They end up first.)

In the linked JSON, there are a few malformed entries. The above program tolerates them, but you might want to fix them. The problems can be found using the following command:

```sh
jq -r '
   def check($type; a):
      a | to_entries[] |
      . as $entry |
      (
         try ( .value.Date | split(" ")[0:4] | join(" ") | strptime("%A %d %B %Y") | empty )
         catch ".data.\($type)[\($entry.key)].Date = \($entry.value.Date | tojson) |",

         try ( .value.Time | split(" ")[0] | if . == "All" then "12am" else . end | strptime(if contains(":") then "%I:%M%p" else "%I%p" end) | empty )
         catch ".data.\($type)[\($entry.key)].Time = \($entry.value.Time | tojson) |"
      );

   .data |
   . as $data |
   keys_unsorted[] | check(.; $data[.])
'
```

Example output:

```
.data.monitor[26].Date = "Sunday 13 December 2020" |             <-- NBSP used
.data.monitor[125].Time = "1.25pm to 2.05pm" |                   <-- Should be 1:25
.data.monitor[127].Time = "Strength and Conditioning Class" |    <-- wut
.data.monitor[130].Date = "Since Monday 23 November" |           <-- Extra "since"
.data.monitor[130].Time = "" |                                   <-- wut
.data.monitor[233].Date = "Sunday 20 December" |                 <-- Missing year
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/mrUixqnYs7)

Comment: @oguz ismail, I've addressed your concerns.

Comment: thanks @ikegami for your example. Looks like source json data format has changed at https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset/nsw-covid-19-case-locations/resource/f3a28eed-8c2a-437b-8ac1-2dab3cf760f9

Comment: seems while the output works, the date ordering seems to be a bit of versus date ascending order

Comment: @p4guru I don't see the change to which you are referring. But either way, SO isn't a code-writing service. I already went above and beyond above (since I was using it to learn, myself), but the idea is to help people write code, no write code for them. There's obviously more leeway given for [tag:jq] questions, but it's up to you to maintain the code and handle edge cases.

Comment: To sort in descending order, just use `reverse` on the result